# How to execute scripts after starting an Amazon instance programatically using php

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I want to do following things:

1) Start an Amazon instance programatically using php
2) Execute a php script on the instance.
3) Stop Amazon instance once the script is executed

Any help on all the three steps would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

AWS EC2 provides ships user-data scripts which allows you to run the program automatically soon after booting the ec2 instance. If you are creating a aws instance using management console you can pass the user-data script and also you can pass the script using cli. User data script is nothing but your bash script.

Have a look at this [blog](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/blog/ec2-userdata). I hope this will help. If you face any problem, please feel free to post.